# Can Smart Reply be customized or influenced in any way?

Tags: zendesk

Google rolled out a [Smart Reply feature](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2015/11/computer-respond-to-this-email.html) a while ago that gives me three possible replies depending on the content of the emails I get:

[image: Smart Reply example]

I don't typically use those replies, however. I tend to be more verbose than Google Inbox. ;-)

However, there are emails I'd love to have a quick response to: [Zendesk tickets](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203691006-Updating-ticket-properties-from-your-inbox). In place of the replies I never use, it would be nice to be able to insert:

```
#status solved
```

I thought maybe using that reply would eventually teach Inbox to suggest it for me, but so far no joy. Is there some way I can customize Smart Reply manually?

Comment: It was my understanding that Inbox would learn over time, so that your "quick replies" would sound more like you.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know any way to do this without an addon, but [Gorgias Templates](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gorgias-templates-email-t/lmcngpkjkplipamgflhioabnhnopeabf) looks helpful.